# confused between Api Controller and oData Controller to use with angular's ngresource

Tags: angularjs, ngresource, asp.net-web-api-odata

i have an angular application that calls web api . it was working all fine with web api controller and ngresource until i required to get count of results.

to get just the count of a result i need to use $inlinecount which only seems to be working with oDataController . with oDataControlelr in place my promises dont work.

```
$scope.totalCount = storeCommandResource.query({ $inlinecount: "allpages", $top: 0 });
```

i get

```
Error: [$resource:badcfg] query
```

please guide.

Comment: I think you haven't pasted the full error message. But what is probably happening is that you are using the resource's `query()` method which expects to receive an array as a response. I'm assuming the response you're getting is just a number (or an object that contains the count), and not an array. If that's true, don't use the `query()` function, use the `get()` function instead: `storeCommandResource.get()` ...

Comment: i get error like 

Error: [$resource:badcfg] get
http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.22/$resource/badcfg?p0=object&p1=array
    at http://localhost:7251/Scripts/angular.js:78:12
    at e.(anonymous function).q.then.p.$resolved (http://localhost:7251/Scripts/angular-resource.min.js:9:330)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:7251/Scripts/angular.js:11546:81)
    at deferred.promise.then.wrappedCallback (http://localhost:7251/Scripts/angular.js:11546:81)
    at http://localhost:7251/Scripts/angular.js:11632:26
    at Scope.$eval (http://localhost:7251.......................

Answer (score 0, accepted):

its look like i can use oDatacontroller with a model builder setup like this

```
            ODataConventionModelBuilder builder = new ODataConventionModelBuilder();
        builder.EntitySet<StoreCommand>("StoreCommandsRest");
        config.Routes.MapODataServiceRoute(routeName: "OData", routePrefix: "api", model: builder.GetEdmModel());
        config.AddODataQueryFilter();
```

and all i needed to change was query to get

```
$scope.totalCount = storeCommandResource.get({ $inlinecount: "allpages", $top: 0 });
```

then i am reading my returned count like

```
response["odata.count"]
```